# counting rows from a cursor in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to count the number of rows that will be returned from an sql  statement . This statement is in a cursor

My code is like this

```
DECLARE

v_counter int := 0 ;

select count(*) into v_counter from (
cursor get_sth is select * from table1 where condit..) ;


BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_counter);


END ;
/
```

and it doesn't work

Is there any other solution that makes me counting the number of rows of a cursor result , I'm really noob

thanks helpers

Comment: Why aren't you just counting the rows in the table that match the condition directly - why the subquery/cursor attempt? (Also - "it doesn't work" isn't helpful; please include the errors and/or wrong results you get).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your aim is to reuse an existing cursor definition and not have to repeat the query it's based on, you could loop over its results to get a count:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  v_counter pls_integer := 0;
  cursor get_sth is select * from all_tables where owner = user; -- your query
begin
  for sth in get_sth loop
    v_counter := v_counter + 1;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line (v_counter);
end;
/
```

You can't count the rows in the result set without fetching them, which the cursor loop does. (@MarcinWroblewski shows another way to that, with explicit fetches). Either way the cursor is consumed by the process. If you want to do anything with the returned data *after* counting it you'd have to re-execute and re-fetch the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

What about

```
DECLARE
     v_counter INT := 0;
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_counter FROM table1 WHERE condit..;
     dbms_output.put_line(v_counter);
END;
/
```

?

If you already have cursor and just want to know how many records it returns, you have to fetch them all

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR get_sth IS
          SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE condit..;
     sth       get_sth%ROWTYPE;
     v_counter NUMBER;
BEGIN
     OPEN get_sth;
     LOOP
          FETCH get_sth
               INTO sth;
          EXIT WHEN get_sth%NOTFOUND;
     END LOOP;
     v_counter := get_sth%ROWCOUNT;
     dbms_output.put_line(v_counter);
     CLOSE get_sth;
END;
/
```

Comment: it works , but i'm looking to optimise my code by getting the number of rows from my cursor without implementing the code in above

Comment: @networker - what do you mean by 'optimise my code' - are you trying to avoid coding the same query twice, and want to reuse the existing cursor declaration? It might help to edit the question to explain what you are trying to do, if this doesn't really solve your problem. (Though you've accepted ti, so...)

Answer (score -1):

```
to optimize runnign time take de cursor code and get into the body code


  CURSOR MOVIMIENTO_ACTIV IS
   SELECT  X.CODMODFUE
         , X.COD_DEP
         , X.CODTIPREC
         , SUM(X.VLR_COSTO)
         , X.COD_ACTIVIDAD
         , X.PERIODO
         , Y.CLASE
         , Y.ESTADO
         , Y.redistri
         , X.recurso
         , ROWNUM NUMERO
   FROM COS_MOVIMIENTO X
      , COS_NIVELES Y
   WHERE X.EMPRESA         = PEMP AND 
         X.EMPRESA         = Y.EMPRESA AND
         X.COD_ACTIVIDAD     = Y.COD_NIVEL AND
         X.PERIODO         = PPER AND 
         Y.CLASE = 'G' AND
         Y.ESTADO='A' AND
         Y.redistRI = 'S'
   GROUP BY X.CODMODFUE
         , X.COD_DEP
         , X.CODTIPREC
         , X.COD_ACTIVIDAD
         , X.PERIODO
         , Y.CLASE
         , Y.ESTADO
         , Y.redistri
         , X.recurso      
         ;




begin

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  X.CODMODFUE
         , X.COD_DEP
         , X.CODTIPREC
         , SUM(X.VLR_COSTO)
         , X.COD_ACTIVIDAD
         , X.PERIODO
         , Y.CLASE
         , Y.ESTADO
         , Y.redistri
         , X.recurso
   FROM COS_MOVIMIENTO X
      , COS_NIVELES Y
   WHERE X.EMPRESA         = '01' AND 
         X.EMPRESA         = Y.EMPRESA AND
         X.COD_ACTIVIDAD     = Y.COD_NIVEL AND
         X.PERIODO         = '201803' AND 
         Y.CLASE = 'G' AND
         Y.ESTADO='A' AND
         Y.redistRI = 'S'
GROUP BY X.CODMODFUE
         , X.COD_DEP
         , X.CODTIPREC
         , X.COD_ACTIVIDAD
         , X.PERIODO
         , Y.CLASE
         , Y.ESTADO
         , Y.redistri
         , X.recurso      


  )W
    end;
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a more detailed explanation of your answer.

Comment: This does not answer op's question.