# Get count value by using cursor

Tags: oracle

```
DECLARE
l_rcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN   
OPEN l_rcursor FOR SELECT * FROM all_users;
dbms_output.put_line(l_rcursor%ROWCOUNT); 
END;
```

This is long code so i cant use the cursor inside the declare portion. Here i need the count of rows fetched. I cant use rowtype because it is a join query.

Comment: `ROWCOUNT` is only set after the records are fetched from the cursor.

Comment: totally agree with @KaushikNayak. Also take a look here [Rowcount-in-refcursor](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20269419/Rowcount-in-refcursor.html) for a similar question.

Comment: But are doing anything else while fetching the cursor? If not, i don't see the logic of using it.... Why not just make query with the into clause and send to a variable. Eg: select count(*) into [variable_name] from ......

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can not.

There's a way to find out whether cursor contains anything (using the `%NOTFOUND` attribute), such as

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_rcursor sys_refcursor;
  3    l_rec     all_users%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    open l_rcursor for select * From all_users
  6                       where 1 = 2;      --> will cause nothing to be returned
  7
  8    -- check whether there is (or is not) anything there
  9    fetch l_rcursor into l_rec;
 10    if l_rcursor%notfound then
 11       dbms_output.put_line('There''s nothing there');
 12    end if;
 13  end;
 14  /
There's nothing there

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

but you can't know how many rows it'll return, which means that you'll have to count number of rows *elsewhere* (probably code that uses what you wrote in your question).

Comment: I am using a with clause for select query so i cannot declare the rowtype in procedure.

Comment: Doesn't really matter, as you can't find number of rows to be returned anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate to [counting rows from a cursor in pl/sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845510/counting-rows-from-a-cursor-in-pl-sql)

You can also just use COUNT in your cursor query to solve your problem, sample code below

```
DECLARE
    l_rcursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN   
    OPEN l_rcursor FOR SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT * FROM all_users);
    -- OR
    -- OPEN l_rcursor FOR SELECT COUNT(1) FROM all_users;
    FETCH l_rcursor INTO v_count;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_count); 
END;
/
```